# How to block subdomains that serve the same content?

Tags: php, url, subdomain, digital-ocean, postfix-mta

I have a project recently I hosted the same on Digital Ocean but the websites is serving following domains:

```
www.example.com,
host.example.com
mail.example.com
webdisk.example.com
webmail.example.com
```

All these sub domains are serving the same content. My guess is that serving same content through different domains are not good so I want to  block them.

How can I block sub domains instead of mail.example.com which is used by postfix?

Why there are different subdomains?

Comment: if i understand your question clearly. you can just reroute your subs to your main directory instead of blocking them if they are visited directly. also i think those sub domain are default reserved subs of digital oceans services.

Comment: @YuukkaLimson Can you tell me how can i do that? also it wont make any problems na?

Comment: host.example.com reserve for your host server, mail is for mail service, webmail is for your mail client. and etc. those have different port which wont be accessible through web browser. it should have no problem. i dont have any digital ocean account so i cant tell you how. in my opinion, you should leave it as is.

Comment: @YuukkaLimson No no my problem is that all these sub domains are serving contents which will negativity affect the SEO so i need to reroute all these sub domains to the main  or serve different http content through them.

Comment: if that's the case. rerouting those subs to your main would do. maybe this could help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/subdomain-redirects-to-the-main-domain

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question clearly. you can just reroute your subs to your main directory instead of blocking them if they are visited directly. 
this may help you with the rerouting 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/subdomain-redirects-to-the-main-domain

also i think those sub domain are default reserved subs of digital oceans services. 
host.example.com reserve for your host server, mail is for mail service, webmail is for your mail client. and etc. those have different port which wont be accessible through web browser. it should have no problem. i dont have any digital ocean account so i cant tell you how. in my opinion, you should leave it as is.

Comment: This is actually serving website that is the problem i am facing

Comment: @Yukka It is not just those subdomain there are infinite number of subdomains which are serving the content how can i stop it?